# How can I simplify the sum of binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Simplify $${k\choose k} + {k+1\choose k} + {k+2\choose k} + \ldots + {n\choose k}$$ for some $n$ and $k$.

I discovered that we can write the sum as $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k} {k+i\choose i}$$ but, unfortunately, I couldn't go further.

Comment: Notice that $\binom{k}{k}=1=\binom{k+1}{k+1}$. Now apply the binomial formula repeatedly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity